# нужно распарсить сложный json на Dart(Flutter)

Tags: json, android-studio, flutter, dart

Вот json:

```
[
    {
        "office": "Пекарня номер 1",
        "sensorTable": [
            {
                "Ok": 1,
                "id": 4,
                "maxTemp": "-",
                "maxTrigerStatus": 0,
                "minTemp": "-",
                "minTrigerStatus": 0,
                "module": 14906218,
                "office": "Пекарня номер 1",
                "sensor": "DS18B20",
                "status": 2,
                "tempCur": 22.6,
                "tempData": "2021-06-01 12:54:50",
                "tempTrigMax": 50,
                "tempTrigMin": -50
            },
            {
                "Ok": 1,
                "id": 5,
                "maxTemp": "-",
                "maxTrigerStatus": 0,
                "minTemp": "-",
                "minTrigerStatus": 0,
                "module": 14906218,
                "office": "Пекарня номер 1",
                "sensor": "temp-1",
                "status": 2,
                "tempCur": 22.6,
                "tempData": "2021-06-01 12:54:50",
                "tempTrigMax": 50,
                "tempTrigMin": -50
            },
            {
                "Ok": 1,
                "id": 6,
                "maxTemp": "-",
                "maxTrigerStatus": 0,
                "minTemp": "-",
                "minTrigerStatus": 0,
                "module": 14906218,
                "office": "Пекарня номер 1",
                "sensor": "temp-2",
                "status": 2,
                "tempCur": 22.1,
                "tempData": "2021-06-01 12:54:50",
                "tempTrigMax": 0,
                "tempTrigMin": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "office": "Склад",
        "sensorTable": [
            {
                "Ok": 1,
                "id": 2,
                "maxTemp": "-",
                "maxTrigerStatus": 0,
                "minTemp": "-",
                "minTrigerStatus": 0,
                "module": 3427178,
                "office": "Склад",
                "sensor": "Стеллажи",
                "status": 2,
                "tempCur": 21.3,
                "tempData": "2021-05-12 00:08:36",
                "tempTrigMax": 50,
                "tempTrigMin": -50
            },
            {
                "Ok": 1,
                "id": 3,
                "maxTemp": "-",
                "maxTrigerStatus": 0,
                "minTemp": "-",
                "minTrigerStatus": 0,
                "module": 3427178,
                "office": "Склад",
                "sensor": "Узел сортировки",
                "status": 2,
                "tempCur": -21.1,
                "tempData": "2021-05-12 00:08:36",
                "tempTrigMax": 50,
                "tempTrigMin": -50
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Код получения данных с сервера:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

Dio dio = Dio();
Future getSensorsList() async {
  final url = 'http://1c.unduty.ru:3014/api/v1/sensorsList?token=c21bf03d52654a66';
  final response = await dio.get(url);
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала добавьте классы-модели, в которые мы положим json данные. Выглядеть они будут так:

Модель с `office` и `sensorTable`:

```
class OfficeSensorsData {
  final String office;
  final List<SensorData> sensorTable;

  OfficeSensorsData(
    this.office,
    this.sensorTable,
  );

  static OfficeSensorsData fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final sensorTable = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json['sensorTable']);
    return OfficeSensorsData(
      json['office'],
      sensorTable.map((json) => SensorData.fromJson(json)).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

И вторая модель для сущностей из `sensorTable`:

```
class SensorData {
  final int ok;
  final int id;
  final String maxTemp;
  final int maxTriggerStatus;
  final String minTemp;
  final int minTriggerStatus;
  final int module;
  final String office;
  final String sensor;
  final int status;
  final double tempCur;
  final String tempDate;
  final int tempTrigMax;
  final int tempTrigMin;

  SensorData(
    this.ok,
    this.id,
    this.maxTemp,
    this.maxTriggerStatus,
    this.minTemp,
    this.minTriggerStatus,
    this.module,
    this.office,
    this.sensor,
    this.status,
    this.tempCur,
    this.tempDate,
    this.tempTrigMax,
    this.tempTrigMin,
  );

  static SensorData fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SensorData(
      json['Ok'],
      json['id'],
      json['maxTemp'],
      json['maxTrigerStatus'],
      json['minTemp'],
      json['minTrigerStatus'],
      json['module'],
      json['office'],
      json['sensor'],
      json['status'],
      json['tempCur'],
      json['tempData'],
      json['tempTrigMax'],
      json['tempTrigMin'],
    );
  }
}
```

В моделях, где я указал тип `int`, возможно нужно будет поменять на `double`, если может прилететь дробное число.

После добавления моделей, мы можем сделать запрос и сразу его распарсить таким образом:

```
Future<List<OfficeSensorsData>> getSensorsList() async {
  final url = 'http://1c.unduty.ru:3014/api/v1/sensorsList?token=c21bf03d52654a66';
  final response = await dio.get(url);
  final responseData = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
    json.decode(response.data),
  );
  return responseData.map((json) => OfficeSensorsData.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```